# show/hide text relevant to a class based on click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a list of products displayed. Once the show more is clicked the text within the extras class needs to be displayed, the show more needs to be hidden and show less needs to be visible. The opposite needs to happen when show less is clicked.

I used the below jQuery code and it works but the problem is that it shows/hide add the extra text in every block. I want it to show only the relevant block.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.extras').css("display", "none");

    $('.showmore').click(function() {
        $(".extras").toggle();
        $('.showmore').hide();
        $('.less').show();
    });

    $('.less').click(function() {
        $(".extras").toggle();
        $('.extras').hide();
        $('.showmore').show()
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="blocks">
    <div class="right">
        <ul class="options">
            <li class="x"><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
            <li class="y"><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
            <li class="z"><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
            <li class="r"><a href="#">Service 4</a></li>
            <li class="k"><a href="#">Service 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="showmore"><a>+ show more</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="extras">
        <p>test text</p>
        <div class="less"><a>- hide</a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="blocks">
    <div class="right">
        <ul class="options">
            <li class="x"><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
            <li class="y"><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
            <li class="z"><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
            <li class="r"><a href="#">Service 4</a></li>
            <li class="k"><a href="#">Service 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="showmore"><a>+ show more</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="extras">
        <p>test text</p>
        <div class="less"><a>- hide</a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="blocks">
    <div class="right">
        <ul class="options">
            <li class="x"><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
            <li class="y"><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
            <li class="z"><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
            <li class="r"><a href="#">Service 4</a></li>
            <li class="k"><a href="#">Service 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="showmore"><a>+ show more</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="extras">
        <p>test text</p>
        <div class="less"><a>- hide</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you set it up on jsfiddle please?

Comment: I wrote a super simple jQuery plugin for this a while ago. you can find it at http://www.eleven11solutions.com.au/blog/jquery-plugins/moreify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you do your logic in relevant sections. **[Demo Here](http://jsbin.com/umocex/1/)**

Try:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.extras').css("display","none");

            $('.showmore').click(function () {
                var parent = $(this).closest('.blocks');
                $(parent).find(".extras").toggle();
                $(parent).find('.less').show();
                $(this).hide();
            });

            $('.less').click(function () {
                var parent = $(this).closest('.blocks');
                $(parent).find(".extras").toggle();                 
                $(parent).find('.showmore').show();
                $(this).hide();
            });

        });
```

Comment: can do `parent.find()` directly? as `parent` is an object? no need to do `$(parent)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.closest()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.extras').css("display", "none");

    $('.showmore').click(function() {
        var $div = $(this).closest('.blocks');
        $div.find(".extras").toggle();
        $div.find('.showmore').hide();
        $div.find('.less').show();
    });

    $('.less').click(function() {
        var $div = $(this).closest('.blocks');
        $div.find(".extras").toggle();
        $div.find(".extras").hide();
        $div.find('.showmore').show();
    });

});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grxhx/)**

Answer (score 0):

try using `$(this).toggle()` in the event handler.

Or I guess more completely, $('.extras').hide(); $(this).show();

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$(this)` to get the relevant content,

so inside the `$(".showmore").click()`,

```
$(this).parents(".blocks").children(".extras").toggle();
$(this).parents(".blocks").children('.showmore').hide();
$(this).parents(".blocks").children('.less').show();
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zFc6X/)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `closest`, `find` and `toggle` to work.
So all your javascript can be changed to the following.

```
$('.showmore, .less').click(function() {
    var $elements = $(this).closest('.blocks').find('.extras, .showmore');
    $elements.toggle();
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Uy9G/)

*References*

- [Closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [Find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)